# Swagger Documentation with two different routes

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I'm currently working on swagger documentation, I have two folders of routes, i.e `route1` and `route2`, in which swagger documentation implemented for each route. Now I want to make different route for both of folders seperately

**For-example**: I want to set route for folder1, i.e `/v1/route` and for folder2, i.e `/v2/route`

But unfortunately, When I set two different route it only pick for `folder2` only. Anyone familiar with this?